# I wan to see the out put of PHP code

Tags: php

I am not a PHP person, but want to see the out put of the following PHP codes seperatly. The ref

```
 $ref = time().mt_rand(0,9999999);
```

and the Hash

```
$task = 'pay'; 
$merchant_id = '0001-0000';
$my_username = 'my_username';
$merchant_email_on_voguepay = 'user@yahoo.com';
$ref = time().mt_rand(0,9999999);
$command_api_token = 'XPuz39v2RFzgdEUbPqcyTMhytstgw';
$hash = hash('sha512',$command_api_token.$task.$merchant_email_on_voguepay.$ref);
```

NB: Please don't worry about the real key, I set it up for experimental purpose.
I have tried to get the out put, but I am getting no where. I need the out put please. I want to compare it with what I am getting with C#.

Comment: just echo it? ..

Comment: I don't know how. I am not a php person, can you get me the out put?

Comment: Googe for echo? You could be able to do that

Comment: echo variable-name; e.g. echo $ref;

Comment: This is a good place to start : http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php

Comment: Is that your real API token for VoguePay? If so, I strongly suggest that you change it immediately, because you've just published your secret to everybody on the internet

Comment: @MarkBaker true and he have done this not only on this question, his other questions have the key

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use echo
---> http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php

```
echo $ref;
echo $hash;
```